# Core data object not nil after deleting from context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm using core data and my setup involves an entity called Track and another entity called Version. Track has a one to many relation with Version. Each version has a file path and id property. I have a view that has a List where the section is a view that displays the track title and each version associated with the track is a row. For testing purposes, i'm currently displaying the version.id and version.filepath in each row. when a version is deleted by pressing the delete button, the following methods are called:

```
track.removeFromVersions(version)
self.context.delete(version)
fileManager.removeItem(at: filePath) //filePath associated with the version
```

when this happens, instead of the row deleting and disappearing, the version.id changes from whatever # was being displayed to 0. If I navigate to a different view and go back to the List view, the deleted row is gone.

I'm trying to understand whats occurring. When I delete the row, version.filePath is nil. I'm wondering why version.id and version itself are not nil after deleting version from the Track and context.

```
struct TrackItem: Identifiable {
    var track: Track
    var versions: [Version]
}


class AudioData : ObservableObject {

    @Published var trackItems : [TrackItem]?

    init() {
        self.trackItems = loadTrackItems()
    }
    
    func loadTrackItems() -> [TrackItem] {
        let tracks: [Track] = DataManager.getTracks()
        var trackItems: [TrackItem] = []
        print("LOADING TRACK ITEMS")
        for track in tracks {
            let trackItem = TrackItem(track: track, versions: track.versions?.allObjects as! [Version])
            trackItems.append(trackItem)
            print(track.title)
            for version in track.versions!{
                let v = version as? Version
                print(v?.filePath ?? "Nothing")
            }
            
        }
        return trackItems
    }   
    
    func deleteVersion(track: Track, version: Version) {
        track.removeFromVersions(version)
        DataManager.deleteVersion(version: version)
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}


// View for displaying Version row
struct SubHeaderView: View {

    var version : Version
    var track: Track
    var audioData: AudioData
    @Binding var itemDeleted: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button {
                self.audioData.deleteVersion(track: track, version: version)
            }
            let versionText = "Version"
            let versionNumer = String(version.id)
            if let filePath = version.filePath {
                let fileUrl = DataManager.loadFileWithPath(lastPathComponent: version.filePath!)
                let lastComponent = fileUrl.lastPathComponent
            }
            Text(versionText + versionNumer).offset(x: 8).font(.callout)
            Text(version.filePath ?? "Nothing")
        } 
    }
}

// View for displaying list
struct SecondView: View {
    
    @StateObject var audioData = AudioData()
    
    @State var itemDeleted: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
             List {
                    ForEach(self.audioData.trackItems!) { trackItem in
                        Section(header: HeaderView(trackItem: trackItem), footer: EmptyView()) {
                            ForEach(trackItem.versions) { version in
                                SubHeaderView(version: version, track: trackItem.track, audioData: self.audioData, itemDeleted: $itemDeleted)
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The list view

[image: List View]

Deleting version 2

[image: Deleting version 2]

Displays version 0 with no file path

[image: Shows id 0]

Version set up

[image: Version set up]

Answer (score 0):

Your published `trackItems` variable will not change when you delete a version (since the array itself is not changing), so it is not causing the view to re-render. The deleted version object is therefore hanging around in memory since you have a reference to it, which often causes you fun crashes.

The `AudioData` object should probably be responsible for carrying out the deletion of the version, and when it's done, it should signal a change:

```
objectWillChange.send()
```

That should update your view correctly.

Comment: Updated my code with additional details. when a version gets deleted, the refresh() in AudioData gets called, which reloads the `trackItems` array. I thought this causes the array to change forcing the view to update.

Comment: modified the code to your suggestions, but getting the same result